# Quasilinear PDE $\left\{\left(x+y\right)\frac{\partial }{\partial x}+\frac{\partial }{\partial z}\:\right\}u\left(x,y,z\right)=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$\left\{\left(x+y\right)\frac{\partial }{\partial x}+\frac{\partial }{\partial z}\:\right\}u\left(x,y,z\right)=0$

This means that

$\left(x+y\right)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}\:=0$

$\left(x+y\right)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+0\cdot \frac{\partial y}{\partial z}+1\cdot \frac{\partial u}{\partial z}\:=0$

This means that

$\frac{dx}{\left(x+y\right)}=\frac{dy}{0}=\frac{dz}{1}$

**Step 1**

$\frac{dx}{\left(x+y\right)}=\frac{dy}{0}$

$dy=0$

When integrating both sides we get $y=C_1$

**Step 2**

$\frac{dx}{\left(x+y\right)}=\frac{dz}{1}$

Because y is an constant we can integrate both sides, we get

$ln\left|x+y\right|=ln\left|C_2\cdot z\right|$

$x+y=C_2\cdot z$

$\frac{x+y}{z}=C_2$

This means our solution is

$u=\Phi \left(y,\:\frac{x+y}{z}\right)$

Right? Also, is there a website where I can check it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can try and verify your answer relatively easily. Let $\Phi = \Phi(u,v)$:

$$\partial_x u = \frac{1}{z}\partial_v\Phi(y,\frac{x+y}{z})$$
$$\partial_z u = -\frac{x+y}{z^2}\partial_v\Phi(y,\frac{x+y}{z})$$
But in general 
$$(x+y)\partial_x u + \partial_z u = \bigg[\frac{x+y}{z} - \frac{x+y}{z^2}\bigg]\partial_v\Phi(y,\frac{x+y}{z}) \neq 0$$
So your solution is not correct. Where you went wrong is integrating
$$\frac{dx}{x+y} = dz \implies \ln(x+y) = z + C_2$$
so 
$$\frac{x+y}{e^z} = \tilde{C}_2$$
The general solution is then
$$u(x,y,z) = \Phi(y, \frac{x+y}{e^z})$$

Comment: ah right, thanks

Comment: No problem. Please consider marking the answer as correct in order to close the question.

Comment: how can i do this? im new to stackexchange

Comment: Here is Stack Exchange's recommendations when someone answers a question of yours: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. But to accept an answer simply click on the check mark in the top left corner of the answer.